# Error: You must specify a network_id in your 'localhost' configuration in order to use this network

Tags: token, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, truffle

I encountered a problem while deploying enj project smart contracts on Ganache by Truffle:

truffle.config.js

```
   

    require('babel-register');
    require('babel-polyfill');
    module.exports = {
        networks: {
            development: {
            host: "localhost",
            port: 7545,
            network_id: "5777", // Match any network id
          }
        },
        compilers: {
          solc: {
              version: "0.4.15"  
          }
        }
    };
```

error:

```
     

    truffle migrate --network localhost
    
    Compiling your contracts...
    ===========================
    > Compiling .\contracts\ENJAllocation.sol
    > Compiling .\contracts\ENJCrowdfund.sol
    > Compiling .\contracts\ENJToken.sol
    > Compiling .\contracts\ERC20Token.sol
    > Compiling .\contracts\Migrations.sol
    > Compiling .\contracts\Owned.sol
    > Compiling .\contracts\TokenHolder.sol
    > Compiling .\contracts\Utils.sol
    > Compiling .\contracts\helpers\TestERC20Token.sol
    > Compiling .\contracts\helpers\TestUtils.sol     
    > Compiling .\contracts\interfaces\IERC20Token.sol
    > Compiling .\contracts\interfaces\IOwned.sol
    > Compiling .\contracts\interfaces\ITokenHolder.sol
    > Artifacts written to C:\Users\98936\OneDrive\Desktop\enj\contracts\solidity\build\contracts
    > Compiled successfully using:
       - solc: 0.4.15+commit.bbb8e64f.Emscripten.clang
    Error: You must specify a network_id in your 'localhost' configuration in order to use this network.
        at Object.validateNetworkConfig (C:\Users\98936\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\environment\environment.js:136:1)
        at Object.detect (C:\Users\98936\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\environment\environment.js:16:1)
        at Object.module.exports [as run] (C:\Users\98936\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\commands\migrate\run.js:19:1)
        at runCommand (C:\Users\98936\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\truffle\build\webpack:\packages\core\lib\command-utils.js:184:1)
    Truffle v5.5.24 (core: 5.5.24)
    Node v16.14.0
```

What solution do you suggest to solve this problem?

Comment: Try network_id : "*"

Comment: I tried it
did not work

Comment: Have you tried running command as 'truffle migrate' or 'truffle migrate --network development' ? I guess 'localhost' network considered undefined as per your config file